# Magento newsletter sign up mail not sending for guest

Tags: magento

Magento sends newsletter subscription mail if he/she is a registered user. When trying to sign up for newsletter subscription as guest user, magento doesn't send an email.

Comment: system >> configuration >> Customer Tab >> Newsletter and check Allow Guest Subscription

Comment: Allow Guest Subscription is already 'Yes'.I can see guest user subscribe list from admin side. The issue is guest user doesn't receive an email when they sign up

Comment: check Success Email Template, can you check that template exist in locale folder?

Comment: Enable display_error using index.php and check if any error causing for email not sending. You can also Enable the log from admin and re-test your process, then check logs. Also don't forget to clear log before re-testing so that it would be easy to find if there any error.